# How to tell webpacker to stop loading .spec.ts files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, typescript, webpack, webpacker

My webpacker config loads all of our test files and helpers for production builds. I need to exclude any files that end with `.spec.ts` and any files that are in `spec/javascript` now because since upgrading to rails 5.2.1 dev dependencies are no longer installed, which breaks the build since the spec files are looking for dev dependencies which aren't there.

I do need to include any that end with just `.ts`, though (which are in the same directories as the ones with `.spec.ts`, per angular community guidelines).

I see that webpacker automatically globs directories passed to `resolved_paths`, so I can't specify my own path there (i.e. the path I really want is `app/assets/angular/**/*[^spec].ts`, not just `app/assets/angular/**/*`). I also tried adding `[^spec].ts` to the `extensions` list, hoping webpacker would generate a path like `app/assets/angular/**/*[^spec].ts`, but it does not.

How do I tell webpacker to load only `.ts` files in `app/assets/angular` that do not end with `.spec.ts`?

To summarize `webpacker.yml` configs I've tried:

```
production: 
  # ... other config

  resolved_paths: ['app/assets/angular/**/*[^spec].ts']
  extensions:
    - .ts
```

and

```
production: 
  # ... other config

  resolved_paths: ['app/assets/angular']
  extensions:
    - '[^spec].ts'
```

Neither of these work. Is there a configuration that will work to tell webpacker to only include `.ts` files in `app/assets/angular` that do *not* include `.spec`?